# probleme when initialize a fileinputstream with a jfilechooser

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, jfilechooser, fileinputstream

To finish a project for my school, I need to do a `FileInputStream` with an .xls file, but when I'm doing the manipulation, it says

> ```
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to find a matching shared formula record"
> ```

on the line `FileInputStream fis= new FileInputStream(selectedFile);`.

Part of the code:

```
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
                    fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
                    int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(panel);
                    if (result==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                        File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();                      
                        String nomFichier = selectedFile.toString();
                        String ext = nomFichier.substring(nomFichier.lastIndexOf("."));

//the bugged part 

} catch (Throwable e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e.getMessage(), "Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                                        e.printStackTrace();

                                    }
```

the full stacktrace :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to find a matching shared formula record
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.record.aggregates.SharedValueManager.linkSharedFormulaRecord(SharedValueManager.java:162)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.record.aggregates.FormulaRecordAggregate.<init>(FormulaRecordAggregate.java:78)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.record.aggregates.ValueRecordsAggregate.construct(ValueRecordsAggregate.java:181)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.record.aggregates.RowRecordsAggregate.<init>(RowRecordsAggregate.java:99)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.model.InternalSheet.<init>(InternalSheet.java:218)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.model.InternalSheet.createSheet(InternalSheet.java:157)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:352)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:398)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:379)
    at javatoexcel.Main$3.actionPerformed(Main.java:148)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace and your code?

Comment: how can i add part of code  on stackoverflow? :/

Comment: Copy the code, select it, and Ctrl+K. Or use the code formatter in the toolbox when you write a post

Comment: that's the part of code :

Comment: One other thing, how do you know it comes from this section of the code, because inheritently RuntimeException is an unchecked exception, see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html

Comment: i don't know but eclipse says to me that the problem is when i initialize the fileinputstream

Comment: The error is unlikely to come from here as this error is thrown by the Apache POI Framework. Thus showing the part of your code manipulating excel would be more valuable to provide some help

Comment: Did you make sure you're using the latest version of Apache POI?